# How can I get Tailwind to respect my set max height?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a few `Radix/UI` `Select` elements on a page. The element `SelectContent` tags have a custom tailwind class applied to them, the class sets `max-h-[200pt]` but it doesn't work and the select just grows to some arbitrary (library set?) size instead. Annoyingly when i change this to `h-[200pt]` the height sets correctly. I'm extremely annoyed at this cos it makes no sense at all. if i set `min-h-[80pt]` it correctly sets the size on the selects with less content. What is it about setting a max height that makes it seemingly impossible?

tailwind class:

```css
.select-content {
    @apply overflow-y-auto max-h-[200pt]  p-1 my-3 w-36 rounded-md
  };
```

react code for the element:

```js
<SelectContent key={itemKey} 
   className="select-content bg-search-panel-element"
>
```

Comment: That sounds like it should work, please include a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: is it possible that you have set `max-height` elsewhere that is applying to these elements and overriding max-heights from Tailwind?

Comment: I've added the code example. and no there is no other max height being set in my code so maybe it's the library that's messing with me? but the thing is max height means if i set a smaller max than the lib then I should be overriding but for some odd reason it is bigger than the value I set like I'm setting a min height 
 @JamesAshok

Comment: @DBS minimal code added

Comment: the above code seems fine, and it should work as expected. A stackblitz / jsfiddle could help debug better... I'd suggest please check `bg-search-panel-element` styles if any `max-height` is present here.. Select the element in dev-tools and see if any `max-height` is added / overridden on the list of styles applied. If no `max-height` is being applied, then your `max-h-[200pt]` class is not getting generated which indicates a tailwind config / build issue...